# How to get useQueries to only fetch once?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-query

I am using 'useQueries' from react-query because the queries  I need to make varies; could be 2, 3, 4, etc...

below is an example of 2 queries, one for 'cat' and one for 'dog'

```
  const [animalQueries, setAnimalQueries] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const animalsResponse = useQueries(
    animalQueries.map((animalQuery) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["animal", animalQuery],
        queryFn: () => catRandom(animalQuery),
        enabled: !!animalQuery,
      };
    })
  );

  const handleOnSubmit = async () => {
    await setAnimalQueries(["cat", "dog"]);
  };
```

For some reason, when I typed enable to !!animalQuery, it keeps refetching because 'animalQuery' is true.

For the normal useQuery in react-query; I solved this with the refetch function:

```
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery(
    ["homePageSearchQuery", { recipeName }],
    () => searchRecipeByName(recipeName),
    { enabled: false }
  );

  const handleOnSearchSubmit = async (recipeSearch: RecipeSearch) => {
    await setRecipeName(recipeSearch.search);
    refetch();
  };
```

But I couldn't get the refetch function from 'animalResponses' as this is an array.

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason, when I typed enable to !!animalQuery, it keeps refetching because 'animalQuery' is true.

I don't fully understand the issue. setting `enabled` will make sure that the query doesn't fire for `undefined` animal names, so if you set:

```
setAnimalQueries(["cat", undefined, "dog"]);
```

you would get two fetches - one for cat and one for dog.

In your example:

```
setAnimalQueries(["cat", "dog"]);
```

you should also see two fetches - one for cat and one for dog. Is that not what you'd expect?

> But I couldn't get the refetch function from 'animalResponses' as this is an array.

Each item in the Array has a `refetch` function so that you can refetch dogs or cats manually. But this shouldn't be needed as `animalQuery` is part of the query key, and react-query will always refetch when the key changes.

Comment: Hi, so currently it is working when I type enabled:!!animalQuery. However, this fires multiple times as animalQuery is true and it queries the server. I am wondering if we can fire the request only once.

Comment: what do you mean with multiple times? It should fire once for cat and once for dog. yes, that's two times, but that should be expected because it's two separate queries ...

Comment: What I meant was, so when the queries fire, it return cat and dog. Which is expected. But then it fires again for no reason. I think it might be because enables is typed !!animalQuery; so it's always true.

Comment: no, react-query will not refetch on every render. There should only be one fetch, and if you e.g. focus the window, you will get another fetch because staleTime is zero per default and refetchOnWindowFocus is on. Anyways, without a codesandbox reproduction, its impossible to understand.